# Entity framework 6 relationship synchronization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

I'm migrating from Entity Framework 4 (Visual Studio 2010) to Entity Framework 6 (Visual Studio 2013) and have some problems with the relationship behaviour.

I'm at the moment using the default model designer tool in Visual Studio that generates all the entity classes for me.

Let's say I have two entities, EntityA and EntityB. I have a relationship between EntityA and EntityB so that EntityA has many EntityBs (and an EntityB has a single EntityA).

In EF4, I could write code like this:

```
var entityA = new EntityA();
var entityB = new EntityB();

entityB.EntityA = entityA;

Console.Out.WriteLine(entityA.EntityBs.Count);
```

and that would print 1. But in EF6, that prints 0.

This also prints True in EF4 but False in EF6:

```
var entityA = new EntityA();
var entityB = new EntityB();

entityA.EntityBs.Add(entityB);

Console.Out.WriteLine(entityB.EntityA != null);
```

I don't really like this behaviour, so is there a way to make it automatically synchronize relationship changes, without having to manually add the relationships at both ends, exactly like it does in EF4? Even if I add the objects to a db context, the relationship updates does not seem to be synchronized.

The generated classes for EF4 looks much more complex than those generated for EF6, so I can understand that something like this doesn't work...

**EDIT:**

After some investigation, this seems to rather be an issue with the new DbContext that was introduced in EF4.1, and has nothing to do with EF6. The older ObjectContext I use in EF4 doesn't have this issue. Even though not recommended, it's still possible to use the older ObjectContext templates by selecting "EF 6.x EntityObject Generator" as Code Generation template instead of "EF 6.x DbContext Generator". To get this to show up, it must first be downloaded as an Online Template.

I still search for a better way than using the old ObjectContext template so I can use the newer DbContext.

Comment: Checkout the `Local` property. E.g. `entityA.EntityBs.Local.Count`

Comment: That property doesn't seem to exist

Comment: I apologize Emil. I meant to say `dbContext.EntityBs.Local.Count` but I realize that doesn't help you. Frankly, after re-reading your question, I'm surprised you are experiencing the problem you describe. I only have experience with Code First, and my experience with it suggests you shouldn't be having this problem.